# HSQLDB times out upgrading large DB from 1.8 to 2.4.1

Tags: java, hsqldb

So I've inherited a legacy application, running on HSQLDB **1.8.0.10** which was having the occasional recovery issue after power losses. With all the improvements to stability and persistence in the last 10 years, I am looking at upgrading it to the latest **2.4.1**.

I have multiple databases to test on. From a few KBs to the largest being **2GB** in size.

Serving up the *second largest* DB which sits at *270MB* (unfortunately, nearly one-tenth of the next size up) posed no problems; Starting the server on the *2GB* file however, caused HSQL to just sit there forever attempting to load the file.

This wasn't an issue on v1.8, which happily started in mere seconds. On v2.4 I've waited up to 10 minutes and gave up (even if it did work in 10m, it's still pretty much unacceptable to have the server take that long to start).

I tried turning on the trace:

```
HsqlProperties p = new HsqlProperties();
p.setProperty("server.database.0", "db/TheDb");
p.setProperty("server.dbname.0", "TheDb");
p.setProperty("server.port", port);
p.setProperty("server.silent", "false");
p.setProperty("server.trace", "true");
Server server = new Server();
server.setProperties(p);
server.start();
```

Resulting in the following:

```
: run() entered
  ...
: server.root=.
: openServerSocket() entered
: Got server socket: ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=37011]
: Server socket opened successfully in 6 ms.
: openServerSocket() exiting
: openDatabases() entered
: Opening database: [file:db/TheDb]
// Stuck here forever
```

The DB consists of the following files:

```
$ ls
 417028772  TheDb.backup
2147483608  TheDb.data
    430165  TheDb.log
       444  TheDb.properties
    196938  TheDb.script
```

And the `.properties` file is currently as follows:

```sh
#HSQL Database Engine 1.8.0.10
hsqldb.script_format=0
runtime.gc_interval=0
sql.enforce_strict_size=false
hsqldb.cache_size_scale=8
readonly=false
hsqldb.nio_data_file=true
hsqldb.cache_scale=14
version=1.8.0
hsqldb.default_table_type=cached
hsqldb.cache_file_scale=1
hsqldb.log_size=200
modified=no
hsqldb.cache_version=1.7.0
hsqldb.original_version=1.8.0
hsqldb.defrag_limit=50
hsqldb.compatible_version=1.8.0
```

No properties are set in the `.script` file. (with the other successful upgraded DBs I did notice that props are mostly moved away from .properties and into .script)

I was wondering if anyone else had performed a similar feat, and/or seen a similar behaviour with large pre-v2 files. Is there a way to have more visibility in the trace to identify problems when loading the data file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to perform SHUTDOWN SCRIPT with version 1.8 before opening the database with version 2.x of the database engine. The data file is regenerated in version 2.x format with this method. This takes a long time but future startups will be fast.

Comment: Thanks for that. Tried doing a `SHUTDOWN SCRIPT` on the 2GB database; it died from lack of space after 3 hours of chewing through my 1TB drive! Is there no way to do an on-the-fly format upgrade without going through an intermediary script file? (i.e. directly regenerate a new format datafile from the old)

Comment: No. It seems there may be a problem with the data file, otherwise the .script file that is written shouldn't be much larger than 2GB.

Comment: I shall investigate. Tried doing a `tail` while it's churning away hundreds of gigs, and all I saw was normal INSERT statements. When I find the time, I might try and debug hsql from source to figure out what is going on with that particular file.